# C Structs in Arrays

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, struct

Assume I have an array which holds some struct defined as follows:

`static struct s x[10]`

Is each element in the array initialized or are they all empty slots?

In another words, what happens if I do:

```
struct s {
   struct s *next;
};

struct s a;
a.next = &x[0];
x[0].next = &x[1];
```

Would `a`'s next point to `x[0]` and `x[0]`'s next point to `x[1]`?

Comment: Have you got some code that compiles? What is `z` - should that be `x`? `a->nest` should also read `a.next`

Comment: I fixed all the obvious typos. It wouldn't help anybody to get derailed onto a discussion about them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this would work just fine. Sounds like you're thinking about Java arrays. In C, if you declare an array of some type, the actual objects are in the array, not just (uninitialized) references to objects.

Answer (score 1):

Initialization depends where and how the variable is defined.  Your code is OK (once confusion over `x` and `z` is resolved), and your statements are accurate.

If it is a file scope variable (as opposed to inside a function), possibly with external linkage, then it is initialized at program startup.  That's fancy-pants talk for a global variable or a file static variable.

```
struct s a[10];
static struct s b[10];
```

These are initialized with zeroes because there is no explicit initializer.

A static variable inside a function is also initialized as zeroes (in the absence of explicit initializers):

```
int function1(void)
{
    static struct s c[10];
    ...
}
```

The array `c` is initialized with zeroes.

Automatic variables are not initialized unless you provide an initializer:

```
int function2(void)
{
    struct s d[10];          /* Not initialized */
    struct s e[10] = { 0 };  /* Initialized - all 10 elements are zeroed */
    struct s f[10] = { &d[0], &d[1], &e[9] };
                             /* 3 are initialized to given values, the rest to zero */
    struct s g[10] = { [9] = &e[9] };
                             /* The first 9 are zeroed; the last is &e[9] */
}
```

The last one is using a designated initializer from C99.

Comment: More precisely, the "storage duration", plus presence or absence of initializer, determines whether an object is initialized.  Objects with "static duration"—which is only loosely tied to the `static` kewyword—are always initialized.  When any object is even "partly initialized" (whether due to static duration, or a given initializer), it is in fact completely initialized, as if with "= 0", resulting in NULL pointers as needed.  For the case of a union, the implied zero is assigned to the first member of the union.

Comment: For some reason, after testing my code, it appears that my results conform with @Ernest's answer. An array of structs (uninitialized) will indeed hold the objects and not just hold references to something nil.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example that will show that you correct with respect to the pointers.

```
int main(int argc, char * argv[]) {
  struct listElement {
     void * next;
  };
  struct listElement listElements[10];
  struct listElement head;
  head.next = &listElements[0];
  listElements[0].next = &listElements[1];
  listElements[1].next = &listElements[2];
  printf("sizeof struct %d\n", sizeof(struct listElement));
  printf("%p \n", head.next);
  printf("%p \n", listElements[0].next);
  printf("%p \n", listElements[1].next);
```

}

Output:

```
sizeof struct 4
0039FE30 
0039FE34 
0039FE38
```

Answer (score -1):

In C never assume any memory will be initizlized for you.

Your example fails cos your array is 'x' but you reference 'z'. Assuming you meant x and z to be the same: you have inited x[0], but x[1..9] are not initialized.